# Converting and Calculating char* expression

Tags: c, string, char

I have the following function, which receives a `tree*` and a mathematical expression `char*`:

```
double calc(char *expr, tree *variaveis){}
```

I'd like to know how to run through the expression verifying each character? I can't use `strtok()` because there will not always be a delimiter.

I was trying something like:

```
double calc(char *expr, tree *variaveis){
    int i;
    dado_t retorno = 0;
    double aux;
    char c;

    for(i=0; i < strlen(expr); i++){
        c = expr[i];

        if(isdigit(c)){
            //Here i need to convert the C value to a double.
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'm having a problem converting the value represented by the character to a double variable. When I debug the code in codeblocks and I set `c` to the digit `2` as a value, it shows me:

```
Variable   Value  
c            50 '2'
```

Then, when I do something like:

```
double aux = c;  or
double aux = (double)c;
```

All I get is the `50` not the `2`.

Comment: "*a math expression*" What types of mathematical expressions need to be supported? In any case, what you want is called *parsing*.

Answer (score 1):

The `50` here is the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of character `'2'`. As, all the character representation of the digits are having successive values,<sup>NOTE</sup> you can do something like

```
double aux = c - '0';
```

to get the digit as the `int` value.

FWIW, i'm not much convinced about the `aux` type being a `double`.

---

NOTE:

From `C11`, chapter §5.2.1

> ..... the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.  ....

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `c - '0'` to transform the character `'2'` to the numeric value `2`:

```
double aux = c - '0';
```

It works because the characters `'0'` to `'9'` have consequent ASCII values:

- if `c == '0'` then `'0' - '0' == 0`
- if `c == '1'` then `'1' - '0' == 1`
- if `c == '2'` then `'2' - '0' == 2`
- etc.